# Using the Solr's grouping, it groups them under a group value which are not really in the same group?

Tags: solr

In the response of a query below I know there are more organisations and they should not be grouped under groupvalue of Maitland, they should be separate like maitland walker. I am using WhiteSpace tokenizer for OrganisationName.

My qyery is

http://solr.xxx.com/FacetedSearch/select/?q=OrganisationName:(maitland*)&wt=json&fl=OrganisationId,OrganisationName&group=true&group.field=OrganisationName"

and the response is

```
{
responseHeader: {
        status: 0,
        QTime: 0,
        params: {
        fl: "OrganisationId,OrganisationName",
        q: "OrganisationName:(maitland*)",
        group.field: "OrganisationName",
        group: "true",
        wt: "json"
        }
},
grouped: {
        OrganisationName: {
            matches: 53,
            groups: [
            {
                groupValue: "maitland",
                doclist: {
                    numFound: 49,
                    start: 0,
                    docs: [
                    {
                        OrganisationName: "Maitland",
                        OrganisationId: 4508
                    }
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                groupValue: "walker",
                doclist: {
                    numFound: 4,
                    start: 0,
                    docs: [
                    {
                        OrganisationName: "Maitland Walker",
                        OrganisationId: 496
                    }
                    ]
                }
            }
            ]
        }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the documentation of the group.field](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/FieldCollapsing):

> Just like normal field faceting, fields shouldn't be tokenized (otherwise counts are computed for each token)

You are tokenizing your field, so the results are based on the white-space broken tokens.

You probably want to use copyField and have separate field for searching and grouping. At least that's the common strategy to the issue you have seen.